# Best practices on testing an orchestrated contract

Tags: testing, unittesting, hardhat

Let's define an orchestrated contract as one that contains at least one function that can be called by another contract - and that contract only.

The function would implement the restriction like this:

```
function foo() external {
  require(msg.sender == someOtherContract, "ERR_NOT_AUTHORIZED");
  ...
}
```

How would one go about writing a unit test for such a function?

I see two possible solutions:

- Replace `msg.sender` with a `getMsgSender()` function that is moved to a library, which is stubbed while testing
- Stub `msg.sender`, but no Ethereum development framework I'm aware of (Truffle, Waffle or Hardhat) can do this

Is there a third solution? None of the above excite me. For the latter I'm at the mercy of the framework devs.

Comment: Depending on the particular test I'd use a mock contract or an EOA directly.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll have to use a bespoke mock contract - but how would you use an EOA in this case?

Comment: In this particular test you can use a EOA to call foo, it should revert since it will not match someOtherContract. Depending on the test I may be able to use and EOA to instead of someOtherContract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a more elegant third solution.

It involves inheriting from the contract that I'm unit-testing and writing additional functions that give unfettered privilege to anyone for modifying the contract storage.

The implementation looks something like this:

```
/* SDPX-License-Identifier: LGPL-3.0-or-later */
pragma solidity ^0.6.10;

contract Foo {

  uint256 public myStorageVar;

  function foo(uint256 newValue) external {
    require(msg.sender == someOtherContract, "ERR_NOT_AUTHORIZED");
    myStorageVar = newValue;
  }
}

contract Bar is Foo {
  function __godmode_foo(uint256 newValue) external {
    myStorageVar = newValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much explained here also https://soliditydeveloper.com/mocking-contracts. ;)

Comment: Using inheritance has the problem you can't access private variables and functions, so you have to use internal instead of private.

Comment: That's true @Ismael, but in my case it works better than the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the someContract member (e.g using a sub-class that can modify this internal member)
2. Move the require into a modifier, and in a sub-class, modify the modifier
3. Use modified vm, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/godmode-for-test

Comment: For 1, changing `someOtherContract` would break my set-up, since it is currently a [MockContract](https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mock-contract.html). I purport to keep my tests as unit tests and not integration tests. For 2, that was mentioned in my OP. For 3, thanks, I'll take a look.